# Macro DIR () List folders and dir () list Subfolders error

Tags: excel, directory, vba

I have made a macro that lists folders of a route and then with the data of list 1, I get a list of 2 folders. But it looks when listing the 2 path is saved in the data of the 1, I do not know how to make each one have its list.

```
'mySourcePath Is the main route of the 1 list
 Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath)
' List the files and directories within "C:\".
mySourcePath = mySourcePath & "\"
Dim fList As String 
Dim fLists As String
Dim fName As String
Dim fNames As String
Dim numero As String
numero = 0
iRow = 2
For inicios = 0 To Total
fName = Dir(mySourcePath, vbDirectory)
'The variable fName now contains the name of the first file or directory within "C:\".
If InStr(fNames, ".") > 0 Then
    numero = Left(fNames, InStr(fNames, ".") - 1)
    ElseIf InStr(fNames, "..") > 0 Then
    numero = Left(fNames, InStr(fNames, "..") - 1)
End If
If numero = "" Then
inicios = 0
End If
Do While fName <> ""
'Store the current file or directory name in the string fList.
fList = fList & vbNewLine & fName
datos = Range("A" & iRow).Value
aux = 0
MsgBox "Ruta 1.1: " & fList
MsgBox "Datos: " & datos
If datos <> fName Then
fName = Dir()
ElseIf datos = fName Then
   'The 2 path modifies to list other folders
    rutas = mySourcePath & fName & "\ASUNTOS\"
fNames = Dir(rutas, vbDirectory)
Do While fNames <> ""
'fLists = fLists & vbNewLine & fNames
' Get the next file or directory within "C:\".
If InStr(fNames, ".") > 0 Then
    numero = Left(fNames, InStr(fNames, ".") - 1)
    ElseIf InStr(fNames, "-") > 0 Then
    numero = Left(fNames, InStr(fNames, "-") - 1)
    ElseIf InStr(fNames, "_") > 0 Then
    numero = Left(fNames, InStr(fNames, "_") - 1)
End If
If numero = "" Then
fNames = Dir()
End If
If numero <> "" Then
iRows = 2
For inicio = 0 To Total
dato = Range("B" & iRows).Value
If dato = numero Then
Range("F" & iRows).Value = numero
ruta = fNames + numero
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(iRows, "E"), Address:=ruta, TextToDisplay:=numero
End If
If dato <> numero Then
End If
If dato = "" Then
End If
iRows = iRows + 1
Next inicio
fNames = Dir()
End If
Loop
iRow = iRow + 1
End If
Loop
fName = fName
fName = Dir()
iRow = iRow + 1 
Next inicios
End Sub
```

Total is how much data is in column E, I run it with a For to buy the data, if it is the same as the name of the folder.
I look in sub folders if there is a name of column H, that is called the same and if so I make the hyperlink.
Example:

Column E:500, 752 , 800, 450, 1052

Column H: Alfredo,  Maria , Ana,  Ethan, Alvaro

Routes:
 C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ 500 
  C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ 800
  C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ 450
  C: \ Users \ user \ Documents \ 500 \ ASUNTOS \ Maria
  C: \ Users \ user \ Documents \ 500 \ ASUNTOS \ Alvaro
  C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ 800 \ ASUNTOS \ Ana

In fList I get:
  .
  ..
  500
  500

I would have to leave: 
  .
  ..
  500
  752